# Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4 - Source Code Unavailable

Tags: silverlight

I'm receiving an error when trying to open the ".zip" file from the appress web site containing the book source code.  Is there an issue I'm not aware of with this file?

Browser:  Internet Explorer (latest version)

I have JZip installed for extraction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the file 9781430272076.zip, downloaded from http://www.apress.com/9781430272076.  This zip file itself contains another zip file, 4638.zip, and this inner zip contains what appears to be the source code for the chapters of the book.

I can successfully open this zip file in Windows 7 using Windows Explorer, and also with 7-Zip.  I received no errors doing so.  Perhaps JZip doesn't like this zip file for some reason.

(Incidentally, saying "I'm receiving an error" on Stack Overflow and not telling us what the error actually is, isn't particularly helpful to us.  We can't always guess at what error you're getting.)